# How can I return a key-value pair from EF ExectureStoreQuery()?

Tags: asp.net, collections, entity-framework-4.1

I have a complex query that returns a number of int pairs (mykey and mykeytype) from a call to ExecuteStoreQuery:

```
  public class myPair {
      public int mykey {get;set;}
      public int mykeytype {get;set;}
  }


  IEnumerable<myPair> list;
  list = _context.ExecuteStoreQuery(sql, param);

  foreach (myPair pair in list) {
     ...do stuff with pair.mykey and pair.mykeytype
  }
```

Is there a way to avoid having to create a class with properties that map to the values returned by my query?

Comment: So the resultset from `sql` has two columns, both `int` ?

Comment: yes, and cols. are named mykey and mykeytype.